# Calculating the Molecular Orbitals of a Molecular State

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, ab-initio

I am performing ab initio calculations on a heteronuclear diatomic compound using the MRCI method on the MOLPRO quantum chemistry package. I obtained the molecular states of the compound but I was wondering how to find the molecular orbital configuration of each electronic state in addition to their associated compositions. I tried to include the "print, orbitals" before and after the CI, but I didn't get anything!
Your help and support are much appreciated...

Comment: MRCI does not optimize the molecular orbitals. They remain in whatever you used as input orbitals for MRCI (typically from a preceding CASSCF calculation).

Comment: I used HF and MCSCF before the CI calculations. Are they generated in the HF or in the MCSCF?

Comment: both methods generate orbitals. but what you are interested in are the MCSCF orbitals (assuming your calculation input is set up appropriately). CASSCF is just a special case of MCSCF.